# extracting particular text from a huge file in java

Tags: java

I have files containing text in pattern like this

```
Type:status
Origin:some text
Text:some text
URL:some url
Time:time
```

around 500 lines with same pattern. I want to extract only the text part from it. I tried reading the file with `BufferedReader` and used `indexOf("Text")` and `indexOf("URL")` and `subString(i,j)` but its giving exception at run time. How can I do this. My code:

```
 FileReader fr = new FileReader("test.txt");
 BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(fr);

 FileWriter wr = new FileWriter("new.txt");
 //  char buffer[] = null;
 String s;
 String str="";
 BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(wr);
 while ((s = br.readLine()) != null) {
     str= str + s;
     i = str.indexOf("Text:");
     j= str.indexOf("URL:");
     String a= str.substring(i, j);
     bw.write(a);
 }
 br.close();
 bw.close();
```

Comment: What is the exception?

Comment: Maybe move `i = str.indexOf("Text:"); j= str.indexOf("URL:"); String a= str.substring(i, j); bw.write(a);` part out of `while`.

Comment: My guess is that the thing you're searching are not present on every lines. You should check for indexes returned by indexof. It will return `-1` when not found.

Comment: You could also show a sample of your input file and post the actual exception.

Comment: what do you exactly want to fetch from the file???? What do you mean by text??? Is it text written in the file or data after the colon.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `"Text:"` is found first in the 3rd line and `"URL:"` in the 4th, but if your program doesn't find both strings, it throws an exception.
Even if it worked you would find the same text over and over again.
Try something like this:

```
FileReader fr = new FileReader("test.txt");
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(fr);

FileWriter wr = new FileWriter("new.txt");
String s;
BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(wr);
while ((s = br.readLine()) != null) {
    if (s.startsWith("Text:"))
        bw.write(s);
}
br.close();
bw.close();
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use

```
String[] pieces = str.split(":");
```

That will give you an array of strings split by what ever you put in the parenthesis. Then if you know the pattern you can get each piece out by iterating through it in a loop. For example: if you know that Type is at [0] and six things in each sequence you can say that the next Type will be at [6] and so on.

Answer (score 0):

You should check for indexes. Of `i` and `j`. If one line is wrong, it will skip it and print the line that is wrong to the console. You should probably handle it in a different way but keep in mind that substring shouldn't love indexes of -1.

```
 FileReader fr = new FileReader("test.txt");
 BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(fr);

 String tokenText = "Text:";
 String tokenURL = "URL:";

 FileWriter wr = new FileWriter("new.txt");
 //  char buffer[] = null;
 String s;
 String str="";
 BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(wr);
 while ((s = br.readLine()) != null) {
     String a;
     str = str + s;

     i = str.indexOf(tokenText);
     j = str.indexOf(tokenURL);

     if (i < 0 && j >= 0){
        // pad with the token string
        a = s.substring(j + tokenURL.length);
     } else if(i >= 0) {
        // pad with the token string
        a = s.substring(i + tokenText.length);
     } else {
        System.out.printl("Unparsed line:");
        System.out.printl(s);
     }

     bw.write(a);
 }
 br.close();
 bw.close();
```

That said, as jonhchen902 said in the comments, you could also check for the strings after the while loop. It really depends on your input file and if you're expecting to find the "string" multiple times or once.

Comment: In this version, it might not be needed to accumulate `str` as I'm only parsing every lines here.

Answer (score 0):

According to your example, `Text:` and `Url:` are on consecutive lines.

Your problem is you're reading the file line by line (`br.readLine()`), so calling `indexOf()` will most of the time return `-1` in `i` or `j` (and you will never find both strings, since they aren't on the same line).

As the javadoc of `substring()` states, calling the method with a negative start index will throw an `IndexOutOfBoundsException`. So your approach isn't right.

You should instead parse the file line by line as you're doing, and simply test for a positive index to the call to `indexOf("Text:")`, and then substring the current line starting at the returned index + 5.

Not tested:

```
while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
    i = line.indexOf("Text:");
    if (i > 0) {
        String text = line.substring(i);
        bw.write(text + "\n");
    }
}
```